# trouble finding CSS tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

i would like to increase the size of the content width on this page:

http://www.yoursdproperty.com/index.php?option=com_jumi&fileid=8&Itemid=34

i would like to stretch it out so that all the content fits

i am not sure what to change in the CSS file:

http://yoursdproperty.com/templates/pjo_joomlaforall/css/template_css.css

please help!

Comment: What is this, your 4th question today asking the exact same thing?  That's almost as annoying as looking at your user name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Echoing sledge regarding Firebug: http://getfirebug.com/

Line 228 is set explicitly at 700px, while the iframe within it is set at 800px.

Also, at line 170 in the CSS, you are explicitly setting the page as a whole to 940px, so that's going to complicate things a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Using a utility like firebug in the Firefox browser can assist you in styling web pages.